# How to add social media component in Sitecore 9.0.1 using SXA 1.7

Tags: sxa, social-connected

I am using `Sitecore 9.0.1` with `SXA 1.7`, want to add a new `WeChat social media` component to my `Sitecore` site. I have added a default LinkedIn to the site and I need other media too. Can anyone please share how to achieve that?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With `Social Media Share` component you can add your own social media buttons by adding them under `/sitecore/content/<Your Tenant>/<Your Site>/Settings/Social Media Groups/Default` item or making a copy of the default and adding/removing the buttons. You need to grab the scripts needed to generate the button from the respective social media platform's developer documentation and fill the `Common Code Snippet` and `Share Button Script` fields.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the other social networks, depending on the requirements I would say easiest would be to implement AddThis for social sharing if you don't require that much customization. If you take a look at the documentation https://doc.sitecore.com/users/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/the-sxa-renderings-and-rendering-variants.html#_Social SXA has a prebuilt AddThis component and you could just add the script there, similar to how it is described in https://tothecore.sk/2018/03/29/social-sharing-in-sitecore-9/

You could also take a look at the `Social Media Share` component which lets you add social network links. If you would like to implement something custom you can look at the approach described https://blog.martinmiles.net/post/creating-custom-sxa-components-with-rendering-variants-and-almost-no-codebehind-on-an-example-of-social-share-buttons

Comment: Just adding a comment here, in case somebody finds this in the future: Oracle is shutting down AddThis starting on May 31, 2023. Sitecore is deprecating the SXA AddThis component.

Answer (score -1):

https://blog.martinmiles.net/post/creating-custom-sxa-components-with-rendering-variants-and-almost-no-codebehind-on-an-example-of-social-share-buttons

Here you go !!! Please have a look on it

Comment: I think along with a link, you also need to mention some information. So that the answer can look more useful to others.